# Error while building Angular project for production 'On Azure DevOps'

Tags: angular, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I'm trying to build angular project for production, I'm using 'docker build' task in Azure DevOps pipeline to build docker image from the dockerfile.

But I got the following error each time.

> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/core-js/internals/define-well-known-symbol.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '../internals/well-known-symbol-wrapped' in
> '/app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/core-js/internals'

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.2.0 as build
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.22

COPY . /app

RUN npm i --save-dev typescript@3.6.4

RUN ng build --prod --output-path=dist

FROM nginx:1.17.6-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80

CMD nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

And here is package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "do-payroll",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.22",
    "@angular-generic-table/core": "^4.17.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@caliatys/s3-service": "^1.1.1",
    "@fooloomanzoo/datetime-input": "^3.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-6-datatable": "^0.8.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^8.8.1",
    "angular-datatables": "^8.0.0",
    "angular-mat-datepicker": "0.0.2",
    "angular-material-datepicker": "^1.0.2",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.610.0",
    "bn-ng-idle": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.20",
    "exceljs": "^1.15.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "format-number": "^3.0.0",
    "igniteui-angular": "^8.2.15",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mat-select-filter": "^2.3.6",
    "message-service": "^1.0.9",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^3.0.3",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "ng2-datetime": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ngx-csv": "^0.3.1",
    "ngx-date-picker": "0.0.24",
    "ngx-export-as": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-loading": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.3.0",
    "ngx-smart-table": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^4.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.13.6",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.63",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.24",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.4",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

But when I run 'ng build --prod --output-path=dist' locally it's working well, even if I build the docker image locally 'using docker for windows' it's working too.

so, how can I overcome this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: I updated the post with the file content.

Comment: Now this is not the issue but why are you running `RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.22`? CLI is already a part of your package.json so it will be installed (same for typescript)

Comment: You could try and clear node_modules as a first step

Comment: Hmm.. It could also be a problem with versions.. try running `ng update @angular/cli@9.0.0 @angular/core@9.0.0` and see what it gives you..

Comment: Last but not least..remove your local node_modules and see if it still works on your local

Comment: @karimalaa Have you checked Mackelito's comments? How's your issue going?

Comment: When I remove 'RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.22' I got 'ng is not recognized' error.

Comment: And when I run 'ng update @angular/cli@9.0.0' I just got warning about 'the current installed CLI version'

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.22` in your dockerfile. Here is an useful blog may help you too:

https://medium.com/@waelkdouh/deploying-your-dockerized-angular-application-to-azure-using-azure-devops-part-2-27245f21dc18

Comment: When I remove 'RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.22' I got 'ng is not recognized' error.